# How can I connect to the database after starting a Django project?

Tags: python, django

I thought of using a Django project as client for a database. The database shall be run in a local network. The Django project is run on local dev machines. Usually one would inject the database connection meta-data (`NAME`, `ENGINE`, `USER`, `PASSWORD` of `DATABASES` dict in `settings.py`) via env vars during Django project startup. Is there a workaround to prevent Django from trying to connect to the database during startup and allow to define the database connection meta-data somehow different during Django project runtime?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand why this would be necessary. Can you clarify a bit more?

Comment: A Django project is usually run on a server, often in a container and connects to one or several database(s) once. I'd like to use the Django project in a distributed application context. The Django project shall be used as database client run on local dev machines, one or several database(s) shall be run in the local network and the Django project shall allow to connect to one and potentially switch between several databases during Django project runtime.

Comment: Why this would be necessary: Due to the need for a distributed application with database reconfiguration options during runtime. Why one would like to have this can vary (data privacy -> one server for every customer, etc.).

Comment: Those databases wont be known at startup, where you could configure *multiple connections*, but they come and go at runtime?

Comment: Exactly. One workaround I thought of would be to use a local, temporary SQLite database for startup and to reconfigure the database settings during runtime somehow. But I'm not sure if this would work at all.

Comment: In [django-sql-explorer](https://github.com/groveco/django-sql-explorer/issues/115) it seems like they implemented something like this. However I could not find the corresponding PR.

Comment: On [djangopackages](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/live-setting/) there is a whole section about "live-settings".